# How to get the content from a website using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I amm trying to get the data from a website. With this code:

```
@WebServlet(description = "get content from teamforge", urlPatterns = { "/JsoupEx" })
public class JsoupEx extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String URL = "http://www.moving.com/real-estate/city-profile/results.asp?Zip=60505";

    public JsoupEx() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
        for (Element table : doc.select("table.DataTbl")) {
            for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                Elements tds = row.select("td");
                if (tds.size() > 1) {
                    System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + ":"
                            + tds.get(2).text());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) parser. When run, I do not get any errors, just no output.

Please help on this.

Comment: Guess people will need much more insight on this! If you are'nt getting any errors, give info like how you are trying to run the program.

Comment: The url in your program does not work. The page contains no tables.

Comment: Are you sure your servlet is deploying successfully? Check your server logs for errors, and include them in your question if found.

Comment: @siddu: The code looks fine. I got the output when I ran it as a standalone application.

Answer (score 4):

With the following code

```
public class Tester {
    private static final String URL = "http://www.moving.com/real-estate/city-profile/results.asp?Zip=60505";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
        System.out.println(doc);

    }

}
```

I get a java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out. I think the particuliar URL you are trying to crawl is too slow for Jsoup. Being in Europe, my connection might be slower as yours. However you might want to check for this exception in the log of your AS.

By setting the timeout to 10 seconds, I was able to download and parse the document :

```
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(URL);
connection.timeout(10000);
Document doc = connection.get();
System.out.println(doc);
```

With the rest of your code I get :

Population:78,413

Population Change Since 1990:53.00%

Population Density:6,897

Male:41,137

Female:37,278

.....

Answer (score 0):

thanx Julien, I tried with the following code, getting SocketTimeoutException. And code is

```
Connection connection=Jsoup.connect("http://www.moving.com/real-estate/city-   
profile/results.asp?Zip=60505");
connection.timeout(10000);
Document doc = connection.get();
System.out.println(doc);
```